# Wordpress - function doesn't close properly

Tags: php, wordpress

So I have a function that I am trying to use on my wordpress site. I am trying to add it into the PHP file but the syntax highlighting in my editor seems to show it not opening and closing properly...

This is what I am trying to use:

```
function friends_get_list($tmp_uid, $friend_status=1) {

    global $wpdb;

    $friend_status = intval($friend_status);
    if (($friend_status != 1) && ($friend_status != 0))
    $friend_status = 1;

    if ( $friends_list = get_transient( 'wpmudev-friends-'. $tmp_uid .'-'. $friend_status ) ) {
    return $friends_list;
    }

    $query = $wpdb->prepare("SELECT friend_user_ID FROM " . $wpdb->base_prefix . "friends WHERE user_ID = %d AND friend_approved = %d",
    $tmp_uid, $friend_status);
    //echo "query=[". $query ."]
    ";
    $friends_list = $wpdb->get_col($query);
    set_transient( 'wpmudev-friends-'. $tmp_uid .'-'. $friend_status, $friends_list, 60 );

    return $friends_list;
    }
```

But the function doesn't seem to close properly. Any help?

Comment: check line 16 of your script. There is an extra double quote

Comment: @DiegoMariani Is this better: http://pastebin.com/2ejpwB9C

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function friends_get_list($tmp_uid, $friend_status=1)
{
    global $wpdb;

    $friend_status = intval($friend_status);
    if (($friend_status != 1) && ($friend_status != 0))
    $friend_status = 1;

    if ( $friends_list = get_transient( 'wpmudev-friends-'. $tmp_uid .'-'. $friend_status ) ) {
    return $friends_list;
    }

    $query = $wpdb->prepare("SELECT friend_user_ID FROM " . $wpdb->base_prefix . "friends WHERE user_ID = %d AND friend_approved = %d",
    $tmp_uid, $friend_status);
    //echo "query=[". $query ."]
    "; // <-loose double-quote
    $friends_list = $wpdb->get_col($query);
    set_transient( 'wpmudev-friends-'. $tmp_uid .'-'. $friend_status, $friends_list, 60 );

    return $friends_list;
}
```

There's a loose double quote on the 16th line. I added a comment after it above.